# How to get distinct element from a list?

Tags: java, linked-list

Below is the book list I do have and is stored via `LinkedList`. I can get the `title`, `year`, `price` and `genres` by their methods using `getTitle()`, `getYear()`, `getPrice()` and `getGenres()`.

I do not have any problem regarding retrieving `titles`, `years` and `price` but the `genres` should which I am getting must be distinct i.e. in the book list I have `Programming`, `Programming`, `Programming`, `Drama`, `Thriller`.

When I use below function then I do get all of the genres which I should get `Programming` only once.

```
LinkedList<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

books.add(new Book("Java",2000,"Programming", "$20"));
books.add(new Book("Swift",2001,"Programming", "$30"));
books.add(new Book("C#",1990,"Programming", "$40"));
books.add(new Book("The Alchemist",2010,"Drama", "$10"));
books.add(new Book("Goosebumps",2010,"Thriller", "$5"));

private void getGenres(){
     for (Genre genre : booksList){
            System.out.println(genre.toString());
}
}
```

I am getting output as:

```
Programming
Programming
Programming
Drama
Thriller
```

But the output I should get is:

```
Programming
Drama
Thriller
```

[image: Help from you guys.]

I hope you understand guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The standard way would be to use a `Set` to collect the genres.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a linked list unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822396/making-a-linked-list-unique)

Comment: All of your genres appear to be different. It's the string representation of them you seem to want to deduplicate.

Comment: Shouldn't `new Genre(..)` be `new Book(..)`? Such `Book` class should simply have `public String getGenre() { return genre; }`. With such setting your code could look like `List<String> list = books.stream().map(Book::getGenre).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry for the typo. It's now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java 8 and newer you can use streams to filter genres from books and then get distinct values:

```
LinkedList<Book> books = ...;

private void getGenres(){
     List<Genre> genres = books.stream()
             .map(x -> x.getGenre())
             .distinct()
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
     for (Genre genre : genres){
            System.out.println(genre);
     }
}
```

Your type `Genre` needs to implement `Comparable<T>` interface:

```
public class Genre implements Comparable<Genre>{

    String name;

    public Genre(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Genre otherGenre) {
        return name.compareTo(otherGenre.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post here your full code? It's working for me so I assume there will be problem outside this method.

Comment: Same output every time. :(

Comment: One thing that might cause some confusion, @PramishLuitel should specify what class is the method `getGenres()` part of and if it is static or not.

Comment: @MichalHorvath I can't use static so it's non-static function.

Comment: @PramishLuitel I edited my answer to show you my full code used for testing.

Comment: @MichalHorvath I have edited my question and added the code picture and it's not working for me anyhow. I have no idea why it's not working. Rest of the code is similar to what you gave to me. But it's only showing all of the five genres.

Comment: @PramishLuitel I see where the problem is. Your property genre is type `Genre` and not `String`. In order to filter out distinct values, your class  `Genre` needs to implement  `Comparable<T>` interface. I will write something and edit my answer in 5 min.

Comment: @MichalHorvath Got it mate and thanks a lot for your help. Really Really Appreciated mate.

Comment: @PramishLuitel glad I was able to help

Comment: @MichalHorvath Really really appreciated for your help. I do have another question again. Would you mind helping on that for me, please? The link to the question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797255/i-cant-access-genre-class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing Michal Code more clearly to you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

    books.add(new Book("Java", 2000, "Programming", "$20"));
    books.add(new Book("Swift", 2001, "Programming", "$30"));
    books.add(new Book("C#", 1990, "Programming", "$40"));
    books.add(new Book("The Alchemist", 2010, "Drama", "$10"));
    books.add(new Book("Goosebumps", 2010, "Thriller", "$5"));
    getGenres(books);
}

private static void getGenres(LinkedList<Book> booksList) {
    List<String> collect = booksList.stream().map(x -> x.getGenres()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    collect.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's showing me all of the genres in my output.

Comment: good answer, just getGenres() should be defined as non-static as @PramishLuitel wrote in comments

Answer (score 0):

It might be overcomplicating the solution, but one way can be to add the values to a set to make sure it contains distinct genres, and later print the contents of the set.

Modify getGenre() method like this

```
private void getGenres(){
  Set<String> genreSet = new HashSet<>();
  for (Genre genre : booksList){
    genreSet.add(genre.toString());
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(genreSet.toArray()));
}
```