# I can't access Genre class

Tags: java

I have a `Genre` class where it has variable `genre` as a `string` and has respective `getters`, `setters` and `toString` method.

The Genre class looks like this:

```
public class Genre(){
    private string genre;
    //The constructor which takes parameter genre and assigns to genre;
    //The respective getters, setters and toString function;
}
```

I have another class called Catalogue which has the following methods:

```
public class Catalogue(){
    private List<Book> booksAvailable;
    private List<Genre> genres;
    public Catalogue(){
        this.genres = new LinkedList<Genre>();

        booksAvailable.add(new Book("Swift", 1999, new Genre("Programming"),20)); 
        booksAvailable.add(new Book("TheAlChemist", 2000, new Genre("Drama"),20)); 
        //Name of a book, year of publication, genre, price
    }
    public void getGenre(){
        System.out.println("I am outside the for loop so I will get printed");
        for (Genre genre : genres){
            System.out.println("I am inside the fo each loop so I will not get printed.");
        } 
    }
}


public class Book {

    private String title;
    private int year;
    private Genre genre;
    private int price;

    public Book(String title, int year, Genre genre, int price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.price = price;
    }
//Here we have getters and setters and toString function.
}
```

When I do add all of the above books, I can get all the information from Books class but not from the Genre class. For example, I can get bookName, bookPrice, bookGenre and bookYear. But from Genre class, I can't get any if the genres.

When I run the above function I do not get output inside of for-each loop but I do get the output of outside the for-each loop.

I don't have any clue why it's happening.

As I do have the same function and for Book class but I can get all of the information of a book class in the catalogue class but not from Genre class.

Why can't I get the genre information from the catalogue?

Comment: `for (Genre genre : genres){` You never put anything in the `genres` list.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Sorry! for typo. I have edited the question. Hope you understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Pramish, welcome to StackOverflow. you seem to use the constructor of the ```Book``` class to add new ```Genre``` instances. But they probably do not get added to your List of genres. Please post also the Book class constructor.

Comment: @luksch Thanks for your reply. I have added the Book class and its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JohnnyMopp mentioned above, you don't add any genre into list. Change your code like following:

```
    public Catalogue() {
        this.genres = new LinkedList<Genre>();
        Genre programming = new Genre("Programming");
        Genre drama = new Genre("Drama");
        this.genres.add(programming);
        this.genres.add(drama);

        booksAvailable.add(new Book("Swift", 1999, programming, 20));
        booksAvailable.add(new Book("TheAlChemist", 2000, drama, 20));
        //Name of a book, year of publication, genre, price
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another function where I do have to add books. And this method will not dynamically add genres.